# Group data in a cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have the following data:

```
Names={A1 A2 B1 B2 C1 C2 C3}
Doserate=(2.2 3.4 6.4 3.4 2.3 4.5 7.5)
Time=(5 7.8 9 3.5 10.2 5.6 7.8)
```

The order of `Doserate` and `Time` is such they correspond to `Names`. I would like to make groups starting with the same letter so that I can perform calculations using `Doserate` and `Time` corresponding to that group. `Names` can vary to even more letters (A-Z) or more numbers like (A1-A30).

How can I group these entries?

Answer (score 1):

```
Names={'A1' 'A2' 'B1' 'B2' 'C1' 'C2' 'C3'};
first_letter = blanks(numel(Names));
for ii = 1:numel(Names)
    first_letter(ii) = Names{ii}(1);  % Grab the first letter
end
[a, b, c] = unique(first_letter)

a =

ABC


b =

     2     4     7


c =

     1     1     2     2     3     3     3
```

You can use a loop to extract the first character in each cell entry (you can probably use `cellfun()` as well) and then a call to `unique()` to extract the unique characters. Its third output, named `c` in my example, will be your groups. Thus `Doserate(c(c==2))` will return all `Doserate` entries where `Names` start with `B`.

Answer (score 0):

To extract one or more letters from the start of your names, you can use regex:

```
Names = {'A1' 'A2' 'B1' 'B2' 'C1' 'C2' 'C3'};
N = regexp( Names, '^[a-zA-Z]+', 'match', 'once' )
% >> N = {'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'};
```

Then you can use `findgroups` to group them

```
[gidx,gnames] = findgroups(N)

gidx =
     1     1     2     2     3     3     3
gnames =
    {'A', 'B', 'C'}
```

i.e. now anything where `gidx == 2` matches the group `'B'` (2nd element in `gnames`).